# Fitting a 2D gaussian profile onto a focal spot

Tags: python, physics, gaussian

I've been trying to write code to fit a 2D Gaussian profile onto some data for a focal spot. However everytime I use my code, it outputs diagonal lines for the plot. Can anyone help?

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

def pixel_values(filename):
       data_raw = image.imread(filename)
       data= data_raw.ravel()
       return (data)

def power(filename):
    pixel=pixel_values(filename)
    intensity=np.ravel(pixel)**2
    total_intensity=sum(intensity)
    print(np.sqrt(total_intensity))

def get_highest_pixel(filename):
    data= pixel_values(filename)
    highest_pixel=np.amax(data)
    pixel_index = np.where(data == data.min())
    print(highest_pixel)
    print(pixel_index)
    return (pixel_index)

x = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5 , 601)
y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 601)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
xdata = np.vstack((X.ravel(),Y.ravel()))

def twoD_Gaussian(xdata,amplitude, xo, yo, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):
    (x, y) = xdata
    xo = float(xo)
    yo = float(yo)    
    a = (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    b = -(np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_x**2) + (np.sin(2*theta))/(4*sigma_y**2)
    c = (np.sin(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_x**2) + (np.cos(theta)**2)/(2*sigma_y**2)
    g = offset + amplitude*np.exp( - (a*((x-xo)**2) + 2*b*(x-xo)*(y-yo) 
                    + c*((y-yo)**2)))
    return g.ravel()

def fit_twoD_Gaussian(filename,initial_guess):
    data_raw=pixel_values(filename)
    popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(twoD_Gaussian,xdata,data_raw, p0=initial_guess)
    data_fitted= twoD_Gaussian(xdata,*popt)
    return(data_fitted)

def plot_fit(filename, initial_guess):
    data_fitted=fit_twoD_Gaussian(filename, initial_guess)
    data_raw=pixel_values(filename)
    print('the numbers are amplitude, centre position, then sigmas')
    print(data_fitted)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

    ax.imshow(data_raw.reshape(601,601),cmap=plt.cm.jet, origin='centre', extent=(x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()))
    ax.contour(x,y, data_fitted.reshape(601,601),8,colors='w')
    plt.show()

guess=np.array([175,300,300,0.1,0.1,0,0])
plot_fit('0_0.JPG',guess)
```

The data has in a 2D array consisting of 601x601 pixels. So that's why I create two arrays x and y. This is what the code outputs for a rough gaussian like laser beam. The black and white image is the JPG file

[image: The fitted function is just the diagonal lines]
[image: The original input beam is here]
[image: And this is the original JPG file]

Comment: can you share the input file?

Comment: Yes, you need to show the original `0_0.JPG`

Comment: Just edited my post now, thank you for looking at this

Comment: `twoD_Gaussian` does not seem to do what the function name suggests. Can you explain this fuction?

Comment: Ah it is meant to be a 2D Gaussian function taking in two arrays. I used the .ravel() at the end so that the curve fit can be used.

Comment: it does something very different from a 2D Gaussian. It works with amplitude, offset, theta, and only two variances instead of a 2x2 covariance matrix. Is it safe to just discard and replace this function?

Comment: You can replace it if need be